# Transparent div in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, transparent

How can I display a div with an alpha background in IE > 7.

I've got this css code for all browser

```
background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.30);
```

but it doesn't work in IE 7,8. Don't test it in ie 9 or 10 actually.

Do someone know how to make it work, It's for put a transparent div over an image

Comment: IE as of yet doesn't support alpha channel in color. Hans solution is good, but expand it to multiple `div` with varying transparency for IE only. And while at it, sniff browser for features not browser-engine.

Answer (score 4):

I found the best cross browser option for opacity is to use a 30% transparent png as background of the top div

Answer (score 2):

You can create another div only for background(same size as your div, position abolute etc) and then set it color + cross-browser transparency like 

`.transparent {
   filter:alpha(opacity=30); 
   -moz-opacity: 0.3; 
   opacity: 0.3; 
}`